# Set version Info does not exist error after installing MSBuild Extension Pack for DotNetNuke module creation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, dotnetnuke, msbuildextensionpack

The PC at work finally kicked the bucket and I needed to install MSBuild Extension Pack on my new PC so that I could continue creating DNN modules for my website. For whatever reason after I install it, I am getting the same error as if it is not installed

**Set version Info does not exist in project c:\users\...**

Here is what I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling
- Restarting computer and VS several times
- Starting new project and trying to build it (gives same error)
- Looking online for documentation and/or videos on how to install this properly (no luck)

My current version of windows is win7 x64 and the version of DotNetNuke that I am creating modules on is DNN 6.2.5. The version of MSBuild I have installed is 3.5.14 and 4.0.11. I am using VisualStudio 2012.

Did I miss a step in installation? Should I have used Community tasks?

Comment: Are you using my Templates for Visual Studio?

Comment: @ChrisHammond I will be using your templates once 8.1 comes out. When I started using DNN6 2-3 years ago, we were contracted with R2i to assist in migrating data from ektron. R2i provided us with a module template that I have been using to develop modules. 

With 8.1 we are going to be giving all of our sites a much needed responsive upgrade. Not to mention a good, clean MVC backend. 

Currently on our test server we are using DNN 8.0 - which from my understanding, does not support MVC. Like threepio however, I have been known to be wrong...from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several restarts (and several rinse and repeat of the above 'tried' list), I installed [MSBuild.Community.Tasks.v1.4.0.00.msi](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/releases). After installing this my module template was able to build the project without error. Unfortunately, due to lack of documentation I do not know if you need both the extension pack AND community tasks in order for this to work, only that community was necessary in this case. For this reason I will leave the extension pack installed for now.